# Thread Exception Mode vs. Application Exception Mode

Tags: .net, winforms, exception

[Application.SetUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223898%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mode, second parameter, `threadScope`.

What is the difference between - Thread Exception Mode vs. Application Exception Mode - in other words, setting that parameter to true or false.

The documentation is just plain confusing.

Comment: Doesn't the "remarks" section explain everything?

Comment: Not in my mind.  That's why I'm asking.  What is the difference?